# Orbits of $GL(m,k)\times GL(n,k)$ on the set $M(m\times n, k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am interested in the orbits of $GL(m,k)\times GL(n,k)$ on the set $M(m\times n, k)$, where $(g_1,g_2)\circ x:=g_1 xg_2^{-1}$.

I know that left-multiplication with a regular matrix is basically a row-transformation and right-multiplication a column-transformation. So in total the rank stays the same under this group operation. 
But is it true that for matrices $x\neq y$ of the same rank there always exist column- and row-transformations such that $g_1 xg_2^{-1}=y$?

Comment: Yes. Perform both row and column operations.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a direct solution using the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)

(see for example (https://davetang.org/file/Singular_Value_Decomposition_Tutorial.pdf))

The principle of this decomposition is that every $m \times n$ matrix $M$ can be written in the following way:

$$\tag{1}M = U \Sigma V^{-1} \ \ \ \ \ (\text{=} \ U \Sigma V^{T}) $$

where

- $U \in O(m,\mathbb{R}) \subset GL(m,\mathbb{R})$,
- $V \in O(n,\mathbb{R}) \subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$,  and
- $\Sigma$ is $m \times n$, with "diagonal elements":

$$\Sigma_{11} \geq \Sigma_{22} \geq \cdots \Sigma_p \geq 0 \ \ \text{where} \ \  p=\min(m,n),$$

all other values $\Sigma_{ij}$ for $i \neq j$ being zero (a kind of generalized diagonal matrix). Here is an example with $m=4$ and $n=3$:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}7   &  1  &   1\\
    1  &  -1 &  -7\\
    7 &   -1 &    1\\
    1  &   1  & -7\end{pmatrix}}_{M}=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}   -0.7  &  0.1 &  0.5  & -0.5\\
   -0.1  & -0.7 &  -0.5  & -0.5\\
   -0.7  &  0.1  & -0.5  &  0.5\\
   -0.1  & -0.7  & 0.5  &  0.5\end{pmatrix}}_{U}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 10 &         0     &    0 \\
         0  & 10 &  0\\
         0  &    0 & 2\\
         0   &    0  &     0\end{pmatrix}}_{\Sigma}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}    -1  &   0  &   0\\
     0  &   0   &  1\\
     0  &   1   &  0\end{pmatrix}}_{V^{-1}}$$

Let consider now the particular case $m=3$ and $n=2$.

The orbits can thus be ''represented'' by matrices of the form:

$$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

but in fact, if $a$ and/or  $b$ are nonzero coefficients, they can be "incorporated" into matrix $U$ ; thus, the "representatives" can be taken as:

$$\Sigma_0=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \Sigma_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ 
\Sigma_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

(resp. null matrix, rank 1 matrices, and rank 2 matrices).

From here, the general case is straightforward.

Comment: You absolutely do not need to know anything about SVD to solve this problem. You just need to perform both row and column operations.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I will modify my text in its first sentence  "you need to know the SVD" which wasn't appropriate into "a direct way is provided by the SVD". But I don't deserve a downvoting because I have given a solution and this solution is efficient. Of course, as often, there are alternative solutions.